# How to write text within \begin{verbatim} and \end{verbatim} in same line?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I am stuck on the following problem and don't know how to  solve it.
Here is my problem :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

 \begin{verbatim}'\hfill\end{verbatim} MKS' which puts the word 'MKS' at the far right of the page where as  \begin{verbatim}'\noindent \end{verbatim}MKS' which
 puts  'MKS ' at the far left  of  the page in the same line.

\end{document}
```

Produces :

[image]
But I,d like to produce :
[image]

The text within `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` makes a new line and takes a whole line for this text only within in it. This looks ugly. I want to get it with the other text. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps consider marking some of your questions that have acceptable answers. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

The inline (or short-hand) use of the `verbatim` environment is `\verb<char><stuff><char>` where you specify `<char>` as anything other than `*`. Choose a character that does not occur within `<stuff>`. In your instance, you would use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|'\hfill| MKS' which puts the word `MKS' at the far right of the page where as 
\verb|'\noindent| MKS' which puts `MKS' at the far left of the page in the same line.
\end{document}
```

The `*`-variant `\verb*` prints the spaces as well.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar: You should accept this answer, by clicking the tick mark next to the answer. That will mark the question as answered.